# Parsing All Pages of HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm having problems within my code which works perfectly with one page, but when I try to parse all the 28 pages it doesn't parse 27 pages, but parse only the first one.

The main idea is parse the data from the mentioned url which has 28 pages in overall and I made for loop for it in order to make BS parse from all the pages. However, it parses only the first page, but doesn't parse others.

I would like to get your recommendations and ways to make it work.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

for t in range(28):
    url = "https://boss.az/vacancies?action=index&controller=vacancies&only_path=true&page={}&type=vacancies".format(t)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

    titles = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-title')]
    #print(titles)
    companies = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-company')]
    #print(companies)
    summaries = [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-summary')]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(titles, companies, summaries)), columns = ['Title', 'Company', 'Summary'])
df.to_csv(r'Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are trying to do, but shouldn't you be extending `titles`, `companies` and `summaries` instead of reassigning them?

Comment: The main idea is parse the data from the mentioned url which has 28 pages in overall and I made **for** loop for it in order to make BS parse from all the pages. However, it parses only the first page, but doesn't parse others.

Comment: Righ, so presumably, you want to concatenate the results extracted of each `bs()` call. But you are not combining the results, you are resetting them. In fact, you should be seeing only the result from the **last** page not the first one.

Comment: Thank you, Frank for your comment and I really appreciate it. I didn't pay attention to it beforehand, but thanks to you and @Code Different my issue has been solved and I can parse the data from website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `titles`, `companies` and `summaries` with every iteration of the loop. Simply change `titles = ...` to `titles += ...`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

titles = []
companies = []
summaries = []

for t in range(28):
    url = "https://boss.az/vacancies?action=index&controller=vacancies&only_path=true&page={}&type=vacancies".format(t)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

    titles += [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-title')]
    companies += [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-company')]
    summaries += [i.text for i in soup.select('.results-i-summary')]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(titles, companies, summaries)), columns = ['Title', 'Company', 'Summary'])
df.to_csv(r'Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: nice approach +

Comment: I wonder how could I forget adding + to the variables. It works perfectly now. +1 and accepted your answer as correct one. Have a nice day ahead.

Maybe this will be beneficial for others as well. Good luck.